# php regex allow only english characters in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, character

I want to insert into a textbox only english characters and other special characters like

```
$!@{]{[
```

etc...

but also i want to check if the string contains at least 2 characters of these: (a-zA-Z0-9)

So i thought of this:

```
preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -"?()[]#:/\'_+*%@!~`$><,.;{}|\]/',$string)
```

is this a good approach?

Comment: Curious, why would you want that?

Comment: i have a URL which look like thread/ID/title and i am tryign not to show unnecessary characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No your approach is not good

Try this one. You need to complete the special characters you want into the character class. You need to escape the `]\-^` characters since they have special meanings in the class (depending on their position).

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9].*[A-Za-z0-9])[$!@{}[\]A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tvck)

The first part is a positive lookahead that ensures the two characters of your `[A-Za-z0-9]` requirement somewhere in the string.

Then comes the character class `[A-Za-z0-9])[$!@\{\}\[\]A-Za-z0-9]` where you can put in the characters that you want to match.

The `^` at the beginning of my expression ensures that it matches from the start of the beginning and the `$` at the end ensure that it matches the end of the string.

The `^` at the beginning of your example is a negation of the complete character class, what you don't want I guess, if you want to match for the character `^` put it somewhere else in the class. The `-` in the middle of your class defines a character range that matches everything from `-"`, I don't know what characters that are, but probably more than you want. Put the `-` at the beginning or the end or escape it.

Comment: Thanks, when i try to enter for example "This is a test Text(TEST text) etc etc" gives it as invalid

Comment: Put space and the round brackets into the character class and it will match

Comment: i edited it and it now looks like this: **/^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9 ].*[A-Za-z0-9 ])[$!@\(){\}\[\]A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/** but if i want to add a comma or a question mark or something else i must add them in the brackets... i want to be able to write anything except it has at least 2 characters of a-zA-Z0-9 or its not a spam text

Comment: @fxuser how should I now whats a "spam text"? Can you give clear examples what you want to match and what not (please as a list of strings that can be put into test tools).

Comment: i change how im gonna do it, im going to allow all characters and simply str replace specificly the ones i dont want...
thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

```
$parameter ='(a-zA-Z){2}';
if $string='kasdfhk890';

preg_match($string,$parameter); // 
return false;

if $string='k';


preg_match($string,$parameter); // single char error
return false;

if $string='kuyyee';

preg_match($string,$parameter);// english character only
return true;
```

[You want learn more try this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:.*?[0-9a-zA-Z]){2,}[0-9a-zA-Z$!@{\]{\[]*
```